# Wordpress download.gz

Tags: wordpress

When I want to visit my webshop it now only downloads a .gz file! I already checked the .htacces file but that seems right. Also deactivated all plugins but still not working.. But strangely enough I can visit my admin panel. This is my .htacces file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The problem is only on chrome. Already googled a lot but nothing works!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it better fits on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com Please do **not** double post. Either wait for migration or delete the question here and reask there.

Answer (score 1):

If using WP Super Cache, go to plugin settings->Advanced->Miscellaneous and uncheck: "Compress pages so they’re served more quickly to visitors."

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any cache plugins installed (especially WP Super Cache)? These links suggest they're the culprit: [link 1 (WP Super Cache)](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/all-website-pages-downloading-gz-file-after-latest-update), [link 2 (W3 Total Cache)](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/download-gz-file-when-accessing-site).

**Suggested solution for WP Super Cache**

Update to 1.4.6

OR

Remove the `if` test in line 1454 of "wp-cache.php":

```
if( !is_file( $cache_path . '.htaccess' ) ) {
```

(probably the matching brace must be dealt with too).

**Suggested solution for W3 Total Cache**

Disable *page caching*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had installed W3 Total Cache. Any Idea how I can turn of page caching?

Comment: @jamie Just go to your admin page, then *Performance* on the left menu, then *General Settings*, then untick **Enable** under *Page Cache*.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both lines below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
And Try Clearing Caches or Use A VPN
```